# Can one declare a constructor using a typeded or typename as in Microsoft C in other compilers?

Tags: c++, c++14

Well annoyingly it seems to work in Microsoft C but not other compilers I use.

Especially desirable when using templates.  Maybe I don't know the "standards compliant way" to do this, but It is really useful and i want code to compile on gcc, clang, etc.

```
template<class T, class T1, ... /* messy, verbose */ >
class MyTemplate {
protected:
    typedef MyTemplate<T,T1, ... /* messy, verbose */ > SimplerName;

    // declare a constructor
    SimplerName(int arg) { ... }
};
class SubClass
    : public MyTemplate<x,y... /* messy */ >
{
public:
    SubClass(int arg, blah, blah) : SimplerName(arg) { ... }
}.
```

I get serious barfage with gcc and emscripten

```
In file included from /home/peterk/didi-wasmtest/build/include/artd/Matrix4Base.h:2:
    /home/peterk/didi-wasmtest/build/include/artd/../../../artdlib-cpp/vecmath/Matrix4Base.h:91:21: error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
    inline Matrix4Base() {
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
```

The code in header

```
template<class Real, class Super>
class ARTD_API_ARTD_VECMATH Matrix4ColumnMajorT
    : public Matrix4CommonT<Real, Super>
{
public:
    typedef Matrix4ColumnMajorT<Real, Super> Matrix4Base;
protected:
    inline Matrix4Base() {
        SType().setIdentity();
    }
    inline Matrix4Base(bool asIdentity) {
        if (asIdentity) SType().setIdentity();
    }
    inline Matrix4Base(const Super &src) {
        SType().set(src);
    }
public:
... 
};
```

This all compiles and runs on Microsoft C but all the constructors declared with the typedef names barf on gcc and clang based compilers.

A place I'm trying to use it where I choose which base class based on a macro, but want the subclass not to have to declare two sets of constructors or use a macro to define them.  I tried variants with and without the template arguments. Template arguments are required it seems. This code compiles and generates proper code on MSC from visual studio 2017 but my primary target is gcc and emscripten ( clang )

```
class ARTD_API_ARTD_VECMATH Matrix4f
#ifdef Matrix4f_RowMajor
    : public Matrix4RowMajorT<float, Matrix4f>
#else
    : public Matrix4ColumnMajorT<float, Matrix4f>
#endif
{
public:

    Matrix4f() : Matrix4Base()
    {}
    Matrix4f(bool asIdentity) : Matrix4Base(asIdentity)
    {}
    Matrix4f(const Matrix4f &src) : Matrix4Base(src)
    {}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The template name serves as an injected class name inside the scope of the class template itself. This is standard and valid:

```
template<class T, class T1, ... /* messy, verbose */ >
class MyTemplate {
protected:
    typedef MyTemplate SimplerName;

    // declare a constructor
    MyTemplate (int arg) { ... }
};
```

<kbd>**[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/16cb8c605ee0b339)**</kbd>

You don't even need the alias for the sub-class:

```
class SubClass
    : public MyTemplate<int, char, bool /* messy */ >
{
public:
    SubClass(int arg) : MyTemplate(arg) {  }
};
```

<kbd>**[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/161561496656cb1b)**</kbd>

Comment: @StoreyTeller Hmmm - I get error barfage see additions to question with real example. ( they don't have code format in comments :)

Comment: @peterk - You are still using an alias in your edited code sample. You can define your c'tors as `Matrix4ColumnMajorT(....)` (like I noted), but not with an alias. An alias is [explicitly forbidden](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/special#class.ctor-1).

Comment: @StoreyTeller  Thanks alas it was NOT the issue. It is the arcane GCC error message and obscurity.  It was because there were inner classes declared inside the first class and the "types" were not known and I had to change a bunch of things to typename and a few to typef typename.

Microsoft takes an approach where their typedefs are simply not resolved until things are instantiated and the types are all known and GCC requires a somtimes very difficult to acheive explicit dependency ordering of typedefs and typenames. :|  Now I have to see if it will compile again on microsoft :)

Comment: @peterk - I wouldn't rely too much on Microsoft's approach. Their behavior with regard to templates has been non-standard for ages. [And now](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/09/11/two-phase-name-lookup-support-comes-to-msvc/) they aim to make it standard. So it's best to double check with an already standard compliant compiler.

Comment: @StoreyTeller I agree but I will say being able to access members in templates used as a base class in a template trom within the template that base base directly without having to use BaseType::member is nice. If I pass in a templated base class into a template it uses as a base I have to qualify all access to it's members with gcc. but then with microsoft where if I pass into the template the subclass I can't static_cast the "this" in the template to it's subclass type passed into the template, where on gcc that is proper.  Oh well :|